Innacurate KNN implementation in R using shiny
This simple shiny app let's you upload an image that then is analyzed by knn algorithm (trained with mnist dataset) and evaluates the number the image contains. The website works properly, assuming that the image that you upload is in .jpg format and its size is 28x28. There are no errors raised.
if(!require(class)) {
  install.packages("class")
}
if(!require(dslabs)) {
  install.packages("dslabs")
}
if(!require(shiny)) {
  install.packages("shiny")
}

library(class)
library(dslabs)
library(shiny)

m <- read_mnist()

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(
    "FIRST AI IMPLEMENTATION: guessing numbers on images"
  ),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel = sidebarPanel(
      wellPanel(
        fileInput(
          inputId = "file",
          label = "Select a number-like image:",
          accept = c("image/jpg", "image/jpeg")
        ),
        actionButton(
          inputId = "predict",
          label = "Guess it!"
        )
      )
    ),
    mainPanel = mainPanel(
      tags$h3("LOADED IMAGE:"),
      uiOutput("image_ui"),
      tags$h3("PREDICTION:"),
      textOutput(
        outputId = "prediction"
      )
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$predict, {
    image_data <- reactive({
      req(input$file)
      img <- jpeg::readJPEG(input$file$datapath)
      img <- as.vector(t(trunc(img[, , 1] * 255)))
      print(m$train$images[1, ])
      print(img)
      return(img)
    })
    
    prediction <- eventReactive(input$predict, {
      req(image_data())
      user_img <- image_data()
      pred <- knn(train = m$train$images, user_img, m$train$labels, k = 3)
      return(as.numeric(pred))
    })
    
    output$image_ui <- renderUI({
      req(input$file)
      tags$img(
        src = base64enc::dataURI(
          file = input$file$datapath, 
          mime = input$file$type
        ),
        width = "280px",
        height = "280px"
      )
    })
    
    output$prediction <- renderText({
      req(prediction())
      paste("The image represents the following number:", prediction())
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


However, the output is not accurate at all. Should I change the value of k? Is the processing of the image formatting the data right? Is the knn algorithm not suitable for this task? Are there any other possibly conflicting issues?
I have tried uploading some black background and white foreground images of 28x28 generated with Paint. The predictions confuse almost every number. Here's an execution example (the image is resized in the app, the original has the correct size):

This are some of the images I have tried.
Number 1:

Number 6:

Number 7:


As this isn't a programming question, I'm voting to migrate.
